# jquery ajax response: difference between Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I'm not a front-end developer, and I'm working on a casual project, which requires AJAX getting a piece of JSON.

```
$('#btn1').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://mywebsite.com/persons/mike',
        type: "get",
        success: function(response, textStatus, jqXHR){
            var age1 = JSON.parse(response).data.age; // works for Firefox
            var age2 = response.data.age; // works for Chrome
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            console.log('Error')
        },
        complete: function(){
            console.log('Complete')
        }
    });
});
```

I use Firebug in Firefox and Developer Tools in Chrome. The `response` is of type `Object` in Chrome, and is a `String` in Firefox.

Is there a generic way to do AJAX in jQuery and successfully parse the response?

Comment: Your server is probably not setting the proper response headers to make jQuery understand it's JSON in both browsers.

Comment: @bfavaretto the server side uses Jersey and the endpoint is annotated `@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)`.

Comment: Weird, the Intelligent Guess should parse it in Firefox then. Maybe check the response headers from Firebug's Net tab to see if the browser actually receives that header. Nevertheless forcing the response to be parsed as JSON will take care of the issue.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté I just looked. Its `Content-Type` is `application/json`, but the `response` is a string if I comment out `dataType: 'json'`. I'm going to keep the `dataType` option in `$.ajax`. Thanks.

Comment: Ok. `=]` Might be a bug with `jQuery.ajax`'s Intelligent Guess then.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set `dataType: 'json'` in your `$.ajax`.

This will force the response inside the `success`/`done` handler to be an already parsed object, else, in case the response is not valid JSON, the `error`/`fail` handler will be called.

Note: Using `dataType` will force the response to be parsed as JSON even if you don't specify a `Content-Type: application/json` header in the response.

If you specify the header though, `jQuery.ajax`'s Intelligent Guess would parse the response as an object even if you don't specify the `dataType`.

So, you can either use the `dataType: 'json'` in `$.ajax` or output the header `Content-Type: application/json` from the back-end and it will work fine. Or both if you want to be throughout. `=]`

Comment: I really couldn't figure out why my mustache template wasn't working.  Once I set the dataType it worked.  Saved me a bunch of time, thank you!